# sending imageviews from one activity to the other

Tags: android, image, android-intent, imageview

I was trying to send some imageviews from one activity to the other,I have also seen other questions similar to this one and the suggestions regarding sending the ID of the imageview from one activity to the other,but  in my case the difference is i am sending more than one imageviews,and also these imageviews are created dyamically from a Bigger imageview,
i.e I am creating 12 small imageviews from a bigger imageview by using
     `Bitmap resized=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height);` in such a way that combination of all of them will give me back the original bigger imageview,
and want to pass them all to the next activity.
Hence i want some suggestions about the procedure i am following,and how can i do it in a better way. 
Thanks !

- **EDIT:** I am capturing a photo using camera,and then assiging it  to some imageview first,then i want to divide this imageview into twelve small parts and assigning to 12 imageviews dynamically,and display each of them distinctly in the next activity.

Comment: You can create an ArrayList and put it in another static class. From where you can access it anywhere in application.

Comment: Why do you want to send image views from one activivy to another? I have no idea what kind of application you are trying to create, but it sounds like a really bad idea. 
Better is to create new imageviews on the next activity and pass data (filename for example) to load the correct image into the imageview.

Comment: @PeterFortuin : see the edit,hope it will help you to understand the thing i am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also required to implement similar case.

First of all you cannot send big bitmap objects through Intents. It crashes the application because Intents, I believe, have smaller capacity like 1mb.

You have following options:

1-Send image file paths through intent extras.

2-Save image file path in a static field and read it in other activity.

3-Save bitmap to the file and send its path using option (1,2) and delete the image file in new activity.

4-Put image bitmaps in a static arraylist of bitmaps and then read it in other activity.

5-Put image filenames in a static arraylist of strings and then read it in other activity.

Basically, you have to recreate them all in new activity or save them in a static field and read there afterwards.

Maybe you can implement more complicated solution like,
if the application have sdcard write access then write it to file 
else save it in memory using static arraylist.

What I do is that, when PictureCallback is getting image data, I save it on sdcard and return the path to the other activities.

Comment: Thanks for the response,but an example with respect to the edit done in question asked by me,might help me in understanding the concept  clearly,if you can...:)

Answer (score 1):

You should never, never ever send the bitmaps directly - just pass the URI or URL or Filename to the next Activity and load it from there...

Comment: @longilong: yea,i got an error saying something about the java binder